# header on HttpWebRequest is not supported in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, proxy

I am working with a requirement where I have to add a custom header to a all HTTP post requests in a Silverlight application to a WCF service running in IIS.

I implemented IClientMessageInspector and IEndpointBehavior, and programatically added the behavior to the client proxy. I followed the instructions posted here:
http://blogs.msmvps.com/paulomorgado/2007/04/26/wcf-building-an-http-user-agent-message-inspector/
http://adilmughal.com/blog/2011/10/wcf-custom-header-with-silverlight/

IClientMessageInspector:

```
public class HttpUserAgentMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    private const string UserAgentHttpHeader = "user-agent";

    private readonly string _userAgent;

    public HttpUserAgentMessageInspector(string userAgent)
    {
        _userAgent = userAgent;
    }

    #region IClientMessageInspector Members

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage;
        object httpRequestMessageObject;
        if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageObject))
        {
            httpRequestMessage = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)httpRequestMessageObject;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessage.Headers[UserAgentHttpHeader]))
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers[UserAgentHttpHeader] = _userAgent;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            httpRequestMessage.Headers[UserAgentHttpHeader] = _userAgent;
            request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

IEndpointBehavior:

```
public class HttpUserAgentEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private readonly string _mUserAgent;

    public HttpUserAgentEndpointBehavior(string userAgent)
    {
        _mUserAgent = userAgent;
    }

    #region IEndpointBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        var inspector = new HttpUserAgentMessageInspector(_mUserAgent);
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Adding behavior to the proxy. Note that I have abstracted the instantiation of a client proxy away into this ClientManager class. My Silverlight application has multiple services which all require the same custom configuration, which is applied through this manager. I have removed the non-relevant code for brevity.

```
public class ClientManager<TClient, TService> : NotificationObject, IClientManager<TClient, TService>
    where TClient : ClientBase<TService>, ICommunicationObject
    where TService : class
{
    private static IClientFactory _factory = new ClientFactory();
    private TClient _client;

    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiates the manager and the client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments used to construct the client.</param>
    public ClientManager(params object[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            _client = _factory.Create<TClient, TService>(args);

            // Add custom behavior to support custom HTTP headers
            _client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new HttpUserAgentEndpointBehavior("this is a test"));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            // The factory may throw an exception when it cannot instantiate the client.
            FaultException = exc;
            throw;
        }

        Client.Faulted += Client_Faulted;
    }
}
```

Now, when I run the application I get the following exception on the first call a service makes to WCF service

> NotSupportedException. 'user-agent' header on HttpWebRequest is not
>   supported in Silverlight.

in the client proxy auto-generated code:

```
        public System.IAsyncResult BeginAutoLoginUser(System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState) {
            object[] _args = new object[0];
            System.IAsyncResult _result = base.BeginInvoke("AutoLoginUser", _args, callback, asyncState);
            return _result;
        }
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: This may be a security restriction. Silverlight is full of those. Just try to set the (non-existent) "user-agent2" header and see if that works. If it does, it means that it's just that particular header is forbidden for some reason.

Comment: @John  I only just got to this issue again. Changing the header to "user-agent2" did the trick. Thanks a bunch! I will upvote if you convert your comment to answer. Else I will add my own answer.

Comment: Well, I wonder what you mean by "did the trick". Is it acceptable to stick with using the "user-agent2" header or something similar in your scenario?

Comment: I created my own header name, something more to the point than "user-agent2". But yes, using a header name other than "user-agent" worked.

Comment: Ok, filed an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to set certain standard headers such as `user-agent`, but you can still transfer the same information in headers by using a nonstandard name, such as `user-agent2`.

Silverlight has a lot of security pitfalls like this.